# get latitude and longitude using zipcode

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to get the latitude and longitude using the zipcode for android application

Answer (score 26):

This is a much simpler solution, assuming the geocoder services are present:

```
final Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
final String zip = "90210";
try {
  List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(zipCode, 1);
  if (addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
    Address address = addresses.get(0);
    // Use the address as needed
    String message = String.format("Latitude: %f, Longitude: %f", 
    address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } else {
    // Display appropriate message when Geocoder services are not available
    Toast.makeToast(this, "Unable to geocode zipcode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  // handle exception
}
```

Comment: Its not working. Giving "Service Not Available" exception.. Do you have better approach?

Comment: This solution is working for all zip codes except for one mentioned here "90210" (unable to find the location for this zip)

Answer (score 4):

There is no rival of Google in GeoCoding :)

You have to just make an **http Get request for the following link**.
Here's [a link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:23456&sensor=false)

Just **change the postal code Element According to your requirements**. And Enjoy.

For further reference follow the link.[Maps Geocoding Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#JSON)

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use a [Geocoding Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding), like the ones provided by [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) or the freely available [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). Note that since you will be just providing a ZIP code, you might not get the results you want due to the inaccuracy of the address itself.

Comment: Also (at least for Google), make sure you fill in as many details as possible, and maybe even set some region options, to ensure the ZIP code is searched in the country you expect it to be. For ZIP code formats that hold spaces, you might want to remove those first, for otherwise Google might only use the first part and show you another country as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20centroid%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%2297217%22) like so: select centroid from geo.places where text="ZIPCODE_HERE"