# Postal code and Address

Tags: android, api, google-maps, street-address, postal-code

How to get an address based on the postal code? Which api should I call? I didn't find the answer from google map platform。[image]

Geocoder can't get the detail address

Comment: A postal code by itself does not usually determine an address (there are a few exceptions), but it is the usually the other way around, i.e. you start with an address then get its postal code back from the API.

Comment: Most apps in Singapore have this feature, based on the postal code to get the address, they can correspond to a specific street or community.

Comment: Aha!  Now your question makes sense.  So this may work in Singapore, but not necessarily in other places.  In the US, for example, the 5 digit ZIP code can cover a large area, and even 5 ZIP + 4 at the end might not mean just one address.

Comment: you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641304/get-latitude-and-longitude-using-zipcode Hope it works for you

Comment: Aha,its not working，Do you have better approach？

Answer (score 0):

Try this `API` for fetching address based on **pincode**.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:90210&sensor=false

Answer (score 0):

Like others pointed out, in some cases there is a one to one correspondence between an address and a post code, like in Singapore where you can use geocode.xyz to convert between them: https://geocode.xyz/508260?region=SG

For USA, you need a zip+4 postal code, for example: https://geocoder.ca/10005-1971?geoit=xml

```html
<standard>
<stnumber>4</stnumber>
<staddress>Wall St</staddress>
<city>New York</city>
<prov>NY</prov>
<postal>10005-1971</postal>
<confidence>0.5</confidence>
</standard>
```